# Moving x or y ticks in Matplotlib up

Tags: matplotlib

I have a numpy array with random values. I have plotted the values in the array using imshow() so that each element shows as a grey-scale square. The problem is that the labels (0, 1, 2 etc) start at the bottom corner. I would like to move them along a bit so they are centred underneath each square. Is there a straight-forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just found http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/image_interp.html
and the most straightforward way is just to have grid(True) ->woohoo!

Comment: `grid(True)` has nothing to do with changing the labels. By default `imagesc` put labels at the center of each square.

Comment: @imsc You are probably right as I don't know Matplotlib well at all. But for what I'm doing, having grid(True) moved the labels along and saved me having to faff about too much.

Comment: Can you post your code/image with grid(True) and grid(False). As far as I know grid is not suppose to move the label. Anyway, it will help others who may face the same problem.

Comment: @imsc the weirdest thing, now my labels are dead-centre under the cells, regardless of grid(True). They seem to have fixed themselves and display in the centre.